# Pyarmor get_expired_days

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation, pyarmor

I have a `license.lic` file generated using pyarmor. But, I dont know the expiry date of the license. Then, I go through the doc, there I get to know to use the `from pytransform import get_expired_days`.

When I called this fuction `get_expired_days()`, I got this error

```
>>> get_expired_days()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pytransform/__init__.py", line 57, in wrap
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pytransform/__init__.py", line 124, in get_expired_days
    dlfunc = prototype(('get_expired_days', _pytransform))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_handle'
```

How to read the `.lic` file and get the expiry date using python?

Thanks

Comment: Unless I am missing something, license.lic is the pyarmor license. It is perperual license .i.e. it never expires (for the pyarmor you have purchased)